# Main Content (for a dashboard) has a scrolling error

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm currently working on making a dashboard for an online community and came across an issue. On bigger screens (1200px+), the right content does not show and is hidden unless you scroll.

I do not want this to happen, and instead I want it all to be on one page with all content visible.

https://gyazo.com/491837d7d7e92093daa4dd41579e4161
(as you can see here, when larger than or equal to 1200px you have to scroll to view what's on the right and it takes up the entire page. However, on smaller screens, it achieves what I want - all on one page)

I'm also using Bootstrap.

Here's the debug view. Just replace `/debug/` with `/pen/` for the code.

http://s.codepen.io/brencode/debug/VjQqAV

Comment: Create valid html to start with.

Comment: @takendarkk, CodePen's editor already has the structure set – all you need to do is just enter the body. Of course, the actual application will have such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move your `col-lg-12` to start after close of the `.portal-topbar` div instead of placing it with `.main--content`.

Also:

- `<p>` tags cannot be placed inside of `<h*>` tags, I changed it to `span` See W3C [Heading Content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#heading-content-0) and [Phrasing Content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1)
- your `<h4>Dashboard</h4>` is not closed.
- your list structure isn't correct (though this may just be because it's a demo better to know then not)
- `.portal-topbar` is aligned now.

**Working Example:** (the background color of the body isn't displayed because of Stackoverflows editor, otherwise it will be there.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous);
 body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.ion {
  font-size: 17px;
}
.icon {
  color: #4f4f4f;
}
.chev {
  margin-right: 4px;
  color: #ababab !important
}
.nav-side-menu {
  background: #1a1a1a;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  width: 230px;
  height: 100%;
  color: #b6b6b6;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
.nav-side-menu .brand {
  background: #1a1a1a;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
  display: none;
}
.nav-side-menu ul,
.nav-side-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-side-menu ul:not(collapsed) .arrow:before,
.nav-side-menu li:not(collapsed) .arrow:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f078";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .active,
.nav-side-menu li .active {
  border-left: 1px solid #74777c;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li.active a,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li.active a {
  color: #d19b3d;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li {
  background-color: #242424;
  border: none;
  line-height: 28px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #272727;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:hover,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
.nav-side-menu ul .sub-menu li:before,
.nav-side-menu li .sub-menu li:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f105";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.nav-side-menu li {
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;
}
.nav-side-menu li:hover {
  background: #FFF !important
}
.nav-side-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #9f9f9f;
}
.nav-side-menu li a i {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.nav-side-menu li:hover {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: #1c1c1c !important;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .nav-side-menu .toggle-btn {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 10 !important;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav-side-menu .brand {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 10px 25px 12px;
  }
}
.nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content > li img {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  .nav-side-menu .menu-list .menu-content {
    display: block;
  }
}
.sidebar-footer {
  background: #1a1a1a;
  position: fixed;
  width: 230px;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  transition: all .6s ease 0s;
}
.sidebar-footer a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-footer a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.sidebar-footer span {
  padding-left: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
.sidebar-footer--aboutdev {
  font-size: 11px !important;
}
.sidebar-footer--aboutdev-bullet {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) !important;
  font-size: 9px !important;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .sidebar-footer {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .main--content {
    margin: 0 0 0 230px!important;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .main--content {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
.portal-topbar {
  background: #FFF;
  border-bottom: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.portal-topbar h4 {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.portal-topbar span {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: right;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .portal-topbar span {
    float: none;
    margin: 5px 0 0 20px;
  }
}
.portal-topbar--back {
  padding-right: 8px;
  color: #333;
  trasition: .5s;
}
.portal-topbar--back:hover {
  color: #000;
  transition: .5s;
}
.tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.65em;
  font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
  background: #000 !important;
}
.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -15px;
  border-right-color: white;
  border-width: 15px 15px 15px 0;
}
.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  border-right: 15px solid black;
  top: -15px;
  left: -3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="nav-side-menu">
        <div class="brand">BRAND</div>
        <i class="ion ion-navicon toggle-btn" style="font-size: 28px;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
        <div class="menu-list">
          <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#service" class="collapsed">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20/f00" alt="" />My Account<i class="icon ion-chevron-down pull-right chev"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="ion ion-grid icon"></i> Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#resources" class="collapsed">
              <a href="#"><i class="ion ion-star icon"></i> Resources <i class="icon ion-chevron-down pull-right chev"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#manuals" class="collapsed">
              <a href="#"><i class="ion ion-clipboard icon"></i> Manuals <i class="icon ion-chevron-down pull-right chev"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#logs" class="collapsed">
              <a href="#"><i class="ion ion-folder icon"></i> Logs <i class="icon ion-chevron-down pull-right chev"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#admin" class="collapsed">
              <a href="#"><i class="ion ion-gear-a icon"></i> Management <i class="icon ion-chevron-down pull-right chev"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-footer">
          <div class="col-xs-12"> <span>© 2016 , v.1.0</span>
            <br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main--content">
      <div class="portal-topbar">
        <h4> <a href="javascript:history.back()"> <i class="ion ion-chevron-left portal-topbar--back" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Return to previous page"></i> </a> Dashboard </h4>
        <span>Tuesday, July 19 11:07am EDT</span> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="alert alert-info">Hello</div>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when
          an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
          with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
          typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
          Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
          specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
          the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised
          in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
          typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
          the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
          it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
          passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
          text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
          It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
          the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
          but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
          PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
          and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
          Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when
          an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
          with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
          typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
          Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
          specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
          the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised
          in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
          typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
          the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
          it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
          passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
          text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
          It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
          the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
          but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
          PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
          and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
          Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when
          an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s
          with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
          Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
          typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
          Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
          specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
          more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
          the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised
          in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
          typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also
          the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
          including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
          it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
          passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
          text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
          It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
          the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
          but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
          PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
          and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
          Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set it to be `col-lg-12` which is full width, but then set `.main--content` to have `margin-left: 230px !important;`. You only see this on large screens because of the `col-lg-12`, which applies the media query to screen widths over 1200px.

I would recommend sticking to Bootstrap columns for horizontal positioning, then using `col-sm-8` for the main content and `col-sm-4` for the sidebar.

Comment: This would've probably been best way to go, thanks for this perspective!